# C - trouble cleaning in stdin while reading input larger then accepted

Tags: c, parsing, stdin

I'm coding interactive sudoku game and parsing commands from the console.

I want to restrict user commands to be up to 256 characters, while any extra char will print an error message and notify him that it exceeds the maximum length.

so I have allocated memory for char array of 256 length, and read this input via fgets function, then passing it to parser function, here is my code for this part -
**Note** that the input is the input I passed from fgets func.

```
Command parseCommand(char *input, int upperBound, MODE* mode){

Command command;
char* token;
char *copyInput = (char*) malloc(strlen(input)*sizeof(char));

if(copyInput == NULL){
    printf("Error: parseCommand has failed\n");
    free(copyInput);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

command.cmd = ERROR;
strcpy(copyInput,input);
token = strtok(input,delim);

if(strlen(copyInput) > 256){
    command.cmd = MAX_ARGS_REACHED;
    clear();
}...//More code following to that but irrelvant
```

now i believe the problem is in my clear function, as nothing happens there and it never leaves it, but if i press enter twich then it's 258 chars it works perfectly, for instance every input of size larger then 257 works perfectly, only problem with 257.

```
void clear(){
int c = 0;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }
```

}

Hope to get help here thanks!

**edit** - here's the code to show how i read the input and passing it to the function above -

```
void runGame(){
Game* game;
char* input = (char*) malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
if(input == NULL){
    printf("Error: Program has failed!\n");
    free(input);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

printf("Welcome to Sudoku Game!\n");
game = createGame();

while(1){

    Command command;
    printf("Please enter a Command\n");
    if(!fgets(input,ARRSIZE,stdin)){/*checks if reading user input failed or EOF*/
        exitCommand(game);
        free(input);
        return;
    }

    command = parseCommand(input,game->rows,&game->mode);//More code following to that
```

Comment: You failed to show how you get `input`, and I assume that your use of clear in inconsistant with that. Anyway you should not mix direct io and buffer processing. As `parseCommand` is a buffer processing thing, it should not use `getchar`, either directly or indirectly and let the caller which did the io use it. That way the possible problems would be easier to detect.

Comment: @user3121023 you correct, but still i need to clean the stdin if i have input larger then 257 otherwise it will remain there and the next time the user enters a command it will obtain the previous input that haven't been read...i can solve it with another if\else but i suppose there's a neat solution. i have added the relevant code showing how i read the input.

Comment: @user3121023 can't edit. it doesn't work properly for chars above 257 since i will still have remaining chars in my buffer, and following user input include previous chars that was above the 257...

Comment: Edited code lacks important info.  I cannot compile it/  What is `ARRSIZE`? for example.  Post a [mcve]

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, ARRSIZE = 256, and I will follow this guide, thanks.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `char* input = (char*) malloc(256 * sizeof(char));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  The cast just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that cast.  2)  The expression: `sizeof( char )` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has absolutely no effect.  The expression just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression

Comment: regarding; `printf("Error: Program has failed!\n");
    free(input);`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  When the error is from a C library function should also output (to `stderr`) the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Strongly suggest calling `perror( "your error message" );`  as that will properly handle both outputs to `stderr`.  2) since the allocation has failed, there is no memory allocated so no need to call `free()`.

Comment: what is the definition of: `Command`?  what is the definition of:  `Game`?

Answer (score 1):

Input array size inadequate.

> I want to restrict user commands to be up to 256 characters
>   ARRSIZE = 256

In addition to [Inadequate memory allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60798417/2410359), which I think is OP's key problem, to read a *line* of input needs a larger array.

`strlen(copyInput) > 256` will never be true with a `fgets(input,256,stdin)`.  The buffer `input` will be at most 255 in string length.

It is not clear if OP considers the <kbd>Enter</kbd> or `'\n'` part of the input.  `fgets()` does.

A *string* length at least 257 is needed to trip `strlen(copyInput) > 256`.

To read a line of up to 257, (without counting the the *potential* `'\n'`), code should use a 256 + 1 + 1 + 1 length buffer.

```
#define CMD_N 256
//                      extra to test too long, \n, \0  
#define BUFFER_N (CMD_N + 1                    + 1 + 1)


char* input = malloc(BUFFER_N);
....
if(!fgets(input,BUFFER_N,stdin)) {
  buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';  // lop off potential \n
  ....

if(strlen(copyInput) > CMD_N) {
```

Comment: @omrib40 `input` is a [buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer).

Comment: thanks, eventually I think I figured another way, I just checked if the last character of the input is '\n' if so then it's not exceeding the limit, otherwise it is.
really appreciate the comment thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At least this problem

**Inadequate memory allocation**

Need +1 for the *null character*.  (Cast not needed in C)

```
// char *copyInput = (char*) malloc(strlen(input)*sizeof(char));
char *copyInput = malloc(strlen(input) + 1);
strcpy(copyInput,input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest:

Follow the call to `fgets()` with:

```
int ch;
while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;}
```

As that will properly consume any left over data in `stdin`